# How to convert latin numbers to arabic in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, numbers, decimal, number-formatting

I use a custom function to convert numbers to arabic format like this :

```
 const numbers = `۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹`;
  const convert = (num) => {
    let res = "";
    const str = num.toString();
    for (let c of str) {
      res += numbers.charAt(c);
    }
    return res;
  };
```

And it works like this :

```
console.log(convert(123)) // ==> ۱۲۳
```

The problem occurs when there is a number with decimals and it converts it to arabic format without the decimal dots for example :

```
console.log(convert(123.9)) // ==> ۱۲۳۹
```

I expect the output to be `۱۲۳،۹` .

How can I convert numbers with decimals to arabic format with decimal dots included with my function ?

Comment: what should it output?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I expect the output to be ```۱۲۳،۹```

Comment: @MahdiFaraji please see my answer with better use of the locale without using country code `AE` for the UAE but using the `numberingSystem`: `arab` for arabic digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `toLocaleString()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

```js
console.log((123.9).toLocaleString('ar-AE'))
```

**Edit:**

with `toLocaleString` options

```
(123.9872512).toLocaleString("ar-AE", {
  useGrouping: false,
  maximumSignificantDigits: 10
})
```

Comment: The problem with using ```toLocaleString()``` is it adds it's own decimals to the number which messes up the number for example ```1000.toLocaleString('ar-AE')``` will output ```۱،۰۰۰``` .

Comment: `(1000).toLocaleString('ar-AE', { useGrouping: false })`

Comment: @evolutionxbox How can I provide an option so it renders the whole number because it only gives me 6 digits for example : ```console.log((123.9872512).toLocaleString("ar-AE", { useGrouping: false }));
     console.log(123.9872512); ``` these console log outputs are not the same it only gives me 6 digits

Comment: Apparently we increase the `maximumSignifcantDigits`. `(123.9872512).toLocaleString("ar-AE", { useGrouping: false, maximumSignificantDigits: 10 })`

Comment: @User863 Thanks for your help . Please make an edit to your answer so I can approve it .

Answer (score 2):

Another way to convert Latin numbers to Arabic by taking care of both the decimal point and the thousands separator is as follows (notice number is passed as a string):

```js
const numLatinToAr=n=>n.replace(/\d/g,d=>"٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"[d]).replace(/\./g, "٫");

console.log(numLatinToAr("12345"));
console.log(numLatinToAr("12345.67"));
console.log(numLatinToAr("12,345.67"));
```

**Another Method is to use the toLocaleString() but do not use the country code as this may change in the future**

Use the `arab` numbering system:

```js
console.log((123.93).toLocaleString('ar-u-nu-arab'))
console.log((4578123.93).toLocaleString('ar-u-nu-arab'))
```